# Slice Array into an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have a function:

```
function sliceArrayIntoGroups(arr, size) {
  var slicedArray = arr.slice(0, size);

  return slicedArray;
}
```

I am looking to take an array and slice it into an array of arrays.. how would I go about doing so?

So if I had this:

```
sliceArrayIntoGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

The result should be:

```
[["a","b"],["c","d"]]
```

But I don't know how to save the second part of the original array after slicing it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This looks like array chunking and I should recommend to you this: http://locutus.io/php/array/array_chunk/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution using regular `while` loop and custom `step` parameter:

```js
function sliceArrayIntoGroups(arr, size) {
  var step = 0, sliceArr = [], len = arr.length;
  while (step < len) {
    sliceArr.push(arr.slice(step, step += size));
  }
  return sliceArr;
}

console.log(sliceArrayIntoGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
console.log(sliceArrayIntoGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], 2));
console.log(sliceArrayIntoGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], 3));
```

`step` option points to an offset of each extraction(slicing)

Answer (score 3):

This ought to do it. It's a simple recursive function that slices *n* elements from the beginning of the array and calls itself with the remaining elements.

```js
function sliceArrayIntoGroups(arr, size) {
  if (arr.length === 0) { return arr; }
  return [ arr.slice(0, size), ...sliceArrayIntoGroups(arr.slice(size), size) ];
}

console.log(sliceArrayIntoGroups([1,2,3,4,5], 2));
console.log(sliceArrayIntoGroups([1,2,3,4,5], 3));
console.log(sliceArrayIntoGroups([1,2,3,4,5], 10));
```

Comment: This results in `[["a","b","c","d"]]`

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I had my operands reversed. Give it another shot. (When I'm at a computer I'll turn this into a snippet.)

Answer (score 2):

try this, it will slice origin array to 2 pieces, then concat to 1 array

```js
function sliceArrayIntoGroups(arr, size) {
  if (size >= arr.length || size <= 0) { return arr; }
  return [arr.slice(0, size), arr.slice(size)];
}
console.log(sliceArrayIntoGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
 function sliceArrayIntoGroups(arr, size) {
   var result = [];

   while (arr.length > 0) {
     result.push(arr.splice(0, size));
   }

   return result;
 }


 console.log(sliceArrayIntoGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], 3));
 console.log(sliceArrayIntoGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
```

```
function sliceArrayIntoGroups(arr, size) {
  var result = [];

  while (arr.length > 0) {
    result.push(arr.splice(0, size));
  }

  return result;
}
```

This will divide array into pieces where each piece will be the size of `size` variable, so

```
sliceArrayIntoGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], 3);
```

will output

```
[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
```

Comment: You should note that this code will mutate the original array, which may be unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object. So using for loop create smallArray and push them to arrGroup array.

```
function sliceArrayIntoGroups(arr, size) {
  let arrGroup =[];
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size) {
    let smallArray = arr.slice(i,i+size);//creating smaller array of required size using slice
    arrGroup.push(smallArray);
  }
  return arrGroup;
}
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce:

```
var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var chunk = function(arr,n) {
    var temp;
    return arr.reduce(function(carry,item,index) {

        //if we're at a chunk point: index%n == 0
        if(!(index%n)) { 

            //if temp currently holds items, push it onto carry
            if(temp && temp.length) { carry.push(temp); }

            //reset temp to an empty array
            temp = []; 
        }

        //push the current item onto temp
        temp.push(item);

        //if this is the last item in the array, push temp onto carry
        index == arr.length-1 && carry.push(temp);

        return carry;
    },[]);
};

chunk(x,5);
```